# Ionic/Cordova build iOS breaks after adding watchOS target

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-watch

Recently I tried to make a watchOS app for our hybrid Ionic app. We added the [Apple Watch Plugin](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch), watchOS target and the extension in Xcode, made sure the supported platforms were set to "watchOS", then proceeded to edit the app and tried to build. But now, the `Ionic build iOS` command fails with this message:

```
Check dependencies




=== BUILD TARGET MyApp Extension OF PROJECT MyApp WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===


Check dependencies
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform


* BUILD FAILED *



The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/<XXXXX>/Progetti App/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,myApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,myApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/<XXXXX>/Progetti App/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/<XXXXX>/Progetti App/myApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

(I edited out username and app name)

Removing both watchOS and the extension from Xcode makes it work again.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Same thing happens with iMessage Sticker Pack

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?